# Find the filename along with directory name in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am doing invertedIndexing in mapreduce. My program gives the output in word with filename. I want to add directory name also with file name.How can I achieve that?

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit();
    String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
    location.set(fileName);
```

output k.txt

Ex- kkk/kk/k.txt

I want kkk.kk.k.txt //whole path

Comment: Can you add your mapreduce code snippet?

Comment: `fileSplit.getPath()` will give you entire path to the file.